# Matrix inserted into identity. Does this matrix have a special name/notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology

I have $n$ positive integers and let $R\subseteq \{1,\dots, n\}$ so that $|R|=r$.

I also have a $r \times r$ matrix called $T$.

I define a matrix that arises from the $n \times n$ identity matrix by replacing the $r$ rows and $r$ columns corresponding to the index set $R$, by $T$.

Say
$$T=\begin{pmatrix} 2&3 \\ 4&5 \end{pmatrix} \quad n=4 \quad R=\{1,4\}$$
then my matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2& 0& 0 &3 \\
0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0& 1 &0 \\
4 &0 &0& 5
\end{pmatrix}$$
**Question :** Does this matrix have a special name/notation?

Thank you.

Comment: No special name.

Comment: Knowing the context of this construction, or why you choose to define it in this way, might help in finding an answer.

Comment: In the case of $R = \{1,2\}$, you could write your matrix as $T \oplus I$, where $\oplus$ denotes a [direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum).  It could be said that this is what you're doing "up to permutation similarity"

Comment: Context: I have an n by n matrix X, and I want to apply a similarity transformation to the submatrix of X whose rows and columns are indexed by R. If I left multiply X by my special matrix, and right multiply by its transpose, that will do this.  I cannot assume that R contains the first few indices.